# Submit regular form using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a normal HTML form with inputs, action, etc. already defined inside an Angular controller. However, this form doesn't have a submit button. Instead it has a button elsewhere on the page that is outside the form, but when clicked should trigger the normal form submission process. **In other words, have the external button work as a normal submit button**.

For example (with a very simplified version of what I have),

```
<div ng-controller='sendFormController">
    <form name='my_form' action='/path/to/form_handler.php' method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="form_data" />
    </form>

    <button ng-click='submitForm()">Send Data</button>
</div>
```

I've been looking for a solution to this problem but the only solutions I've been able to find (which are a bit hackish to my way of thinking) include,

- Having a hidden submit button and trigger that with the press of the external button.
- Having code that executes $http.post(), etc. when the external button is pressed. I don't want to have to duplicate the action, assembling the parameters, etc. in the function.

I'm assuming that there must be a way in Angular to simply trigger the submission of the form but I can't find it in the docs. Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

In `sendFormController`,

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    document.getElementById('my_form').submit(); //force to submit the form after clicking the button
}
```

And,

```
<form name='my_form' id='my_form' action='/path/to/form_handler.php' method="POST">
```

Comment: I have considered that as an option but everything I read suggests that touching the DOM directly in the controller is considered to be really bad practice as it tightly couples my controller to the HTML.

Comment: your not modifying the dom

Comment: No, I know I'm not modifying it. But I am selecting from it. This means that if the ID of the form changes for any reason, then I have to remember to go and change my AngularJS code. Or what if I don't know the ID of the form because its dynamically generated? Then I have to inject the ID of the form into Angular!

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to do in a angular way:

```
app.controller('sendFormController', function($scope) {
       $scope.model = { 
          form_data: ''
       };

       $scope.submitForm = function () {
          $http({
              url: '/path/to/form_handler.php',
              method: "POST",
              data: $.param($scope.model),
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
              }
          });
        };
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller='sendFormController">    
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.form_data" />  

    <button ng-click='submitForm()">Send Data</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't change the HTML that much. It really needs to keep the form as is because of the way in which it is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
     <form onsubmit='this.submit()' name='my_form' action='/path/to/form_handler.php' method="POST">
```

or in more 'Angular' way:

```
     <form #form (submit)='form.submit()' name='my_form' action='/path/to/form_handler.php' method="POST">
```